# What route address to set for POST in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have resource controller Articles.

Here is method index, that is called by defualt each time when I open page.

I tried to send form on this address:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'articles.index', 'class' => 'form-inline')) }}
```

It does not work

Comment: You may need to put 'method' => 'get' in the array so it doesn't attempt a post, which is restricted for that route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a resource route in your routes file - something like this:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

That would create all the routes like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc. Then in your controller you would handle it appropriately.

To make a form post to it? Try something like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'articles']) !!}
```

Then when submitted it will POST to your ArticlesController (you can see where by listing all your routes with this command)

```
php artisan routes:list
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be posting to `articles.store`. `php artisan route:list` will show you a list of your routes and the methods they accept.